# Syntax question: accessing a PHP object

Tags: php, object, syntax

I have an object returned from $xml = simplexml_load_file($file). I'm trying to access 'location-id' and 'item-id', but I can't figure out how to access those pieces of info. If it only nested once, I know I could do something like $xml->{'item-id'} but it doesn't seem to work. What is the syntax for this? Sorry for the lack of formatting.. that's how it was returned on my browser.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [item] => Array (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
            [@attributes] => Array (
                [item-id] => AAA )
            [locations] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                [location] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                    [@attributes] => Array (
                        [location-id] => 111
                    )
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [pick-up-now-eligible] => false
                )
            )
        )
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            [@attributes] => Array (
                [item-id] => BBB
            )
            [locations] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                [location] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                    [@attributes] => Array (
                        [location-id] => 111
                    )
                    [quantity] => 1
                    [pick-up-now-eligible] => false
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Could somebody chime in? TIA!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access attributes in SimpleXML, array-style syntax can be used.

```
$element['attribute_name'];
```

The [`SimpleXMLElement::attributes()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.attributes) method is also available.  The above would be:

```
$element->attributes()->attribute_name;
```

If the attribute is namespaced (e.g. `blah:attribute_name`) then you can provide that namespace (as the prefix, or URI) to the `attributes()` method.

```
$element->attributes('blah', TRUE)->attribute_name;
$element->attributes('http://example.org/blah')->attribute_name;
```

See the [SimpleXML Basic Usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) manual page for further information.

---

To put the above into practice for this individual question, to print the `item-id` attribute of the second `<item>` element, you could use:

```
echo $xml->item[1]['item-id'];
```

The example below loops over the `<item>` elements and prints their associated `item-id` and (the first) `location-id` values.

```
foreach ($xml->item as $item) {
    $location = $item->locations->location;
    echo 'Item ID: ' . $item['item-id'] . "\n";
    echo 'Locations: ' . $location['location-id'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it'd be

```
$xml->item[0]->attributes('item-id');
$xml->item[0]->locations->location->attributes('item-id');
```

Comment: Hey Marc, this doesn't seem to be working. There is no error, but nothing is displayed. Could you take another look? (thanks for formatting the code!)

Comment: By the way, I'm trying to print it on my browser with echo $xml->item[0]->attributes('item-id'); Maybe this is an incorrect way?